# JLabel not drawing properly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a loot logger for a game, and when I try to draw my Main Menu title on startup nothing happens. When I call the exactly same code with a JButton it works properly

The code:

```
public Mainmenu(){

    initComponents(); 

    drawmenu();
}
private void drawmenu(){

    Graphics g = jLabel1.getGraphics();

    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));

    g.drawString("Loot Logger v.1.0", 215, 80); 
}
```

But when I call it like this it works:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Graphics g = jLabel1.getGraphics();
    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
    g.drawString("Loot Logger v.1.0", 215, 80); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics g = jLabel1.getGraphics();
g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
g.drawString("Loot Logger v.1.0", 215, 80);
```

Don't use getGraphics(...) to paint a label (or any Swing component).

All you need to do is add the label to the frame and then change the text of the label:

```
jLabel1.setFont(...);
jLabel1.setText(...);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.